# JBoss AS7 deployment error relate with datasource missing dependents

Tags: java, jboss

I have deploy a war file in JBoss AS7 and when i enable it, it gives me the below error,

```
14:00:05,700 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "JSPServletPoc.war"
14:00:29,749 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
14:00:30,156 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (HttpManagementService-threads - 7) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "JSPServletPoc.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.JSPServletPoc.JSPServletPoc.env.jdbc.MySQLDSJndijboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.MySQLDSJndiMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.JSPServletPoc.JSPServletPoc.env.jdbc.MySQLDSJndijboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.MySQLDSJndi]"]}
14:00:30,437 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment JSPServletPoc.war in 236ms
14:00:30,437 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (HttpManagementService-threads - 7) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.resources.jdbc.MySQLDSJndi (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.JSPServletPoc.JSPServletPoc.env.jdbc.MySQLDSJndi]
```

I have already configure a data source as **MySQLDSJndi** and enable it too.

I dont find any problem with setting the data source where i gave the data source name as **MySQLDSJndi** and the JNDI name as **java:/MySQLDSJndi**. Further I have given the user name and password and the connection url as **jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb**

Also i have a doubt why the error message,

```
JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
```

I have checked inside the jar for file named “META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver” because that file is what makes the jar to be JDBC-compliant jar file and it exists too.

Comment: How did you install your JDBC Driver to AS7?  How did you define your Datasource (i.e. did you use the WebConsole or CLI).  Also which MySQL JAR are you using?

Comment: I directly place the mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments. I define the Data source through admin web console

Answer (score 1):

The driver version is not compliant and you would need to first register the driver as a module.

Read through section ***Installing a JDBC driver as a module*** @ [How to configure datasource in Jboss As7](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7)

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL driver is non-compliant because it [doesn't support SQL-92](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62038). AFAIK copying to `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments` [only works for compliant drivers, non-compliant drivers need to be deployed as a module](http://planet.jboss.org/post/how_to_create_and_manage_datasources_in_as7).